# Is it normal for my Paypal IPN script to get hit twice every time?

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently testing an IPN script in PHP, using Paypal's sandbox.

It seems to work fine, except that it seems to get hit twice every time. I put in some code right at the top to just send me an email alert so I know the script has been executed. I get that alert twice with every transaction.

I can even comment out everything in my script except that line, and I still get it twice, so I think I can be reasonably certain the problem is not in my IPN script but something on the Paypal end.

I don't know if this means I've got some setting in my account on Paypal wrong, or if there's a normal part of Paypal workings that I'm not understanding or what's going on. I'm pretty sure my IPN script shouldn't be running twice for every transaction, though.

Is there a reason my IPN script would get hit twice? Is there something I can or should be doing about that?

---

***Updates:***

1. I have confirmed that the double hit happens every single time.
2. There actually is a difference in the two emails I get back. In one there is a `payment_date` variable, and in the second one there is a `subscr_date` variable. The `subscr_date` variable is set to a time just a few seconds after the `payment_date`.

While it would seem that all that is happening is that I am getting two notifications, one for the payment, and one for the subscription starting, this still strikes me as odd. My understanding of the IPN script is that its purpose is so that I can execute changes in my database (or whatever else) based on a successful payment. If they intend to hit me twice each time, then whatever changes I intend to execute will be done twice, which I think is clearly not the ideal approach.

Also, since what a customer is purchasing ***is*** a subscription, it seems they are giving me two notifications about the same thing with a different names each time. Also rather strange.

So I'm still wondering... is this normal, and what should I be doing to prevent my code from being executed twice?

Comment: What method are you using for testing? Are all the variables that PayPal sends you exactly the same both times?

Comment: @animuson: I'm not sure how to answer your first question except to say that I have set up a Paypal "subscribe" button, and I walk through a purchase by pressing it, paying with Paypal (sandbox), and returning to my site. For your second question, as far as I can tell, yes, the variables are exactly the same.

Comment: Depending on how you're testing, PayPal will allow you to manually specify what "type" of payment it is, such as a credit card, eCheck, etc. I've read many sources that state PayPal sometimes just sends things twice and there's nothing you can do about it, but never that they send it twice *every single time*.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758521/paypal-ipn-notification-twice

Comment: @nithi: I don't think that's a duplicate. In that question, the questioner is getting two different responses, VALID and INVALID. I am getting two duplicate responses, both VALID.

Comment: @animuson: Okay, thanks for that. My overall number of tests has been low (maybe a dozen), so maybe I've just been unlucky...? I am going to test more and double check to make sure that it is as consistent as I think it is.

Comment: Please check that your browser is returning 200 OK status to paypal. Try to store the transaction id in database and check whether the current transaction id already exists in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting 2 different IPN events - 1 to confirm the payment and 1 to confirm the start of the subscription.

See the IPN subscription events here http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/notifications.html#1032718 and the IPN subscription variables here http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/Appx-ipn_subscription_variables.html (scroll down to Table A.2) for what you can expect to see in each type.

There are also IPN events, for example to mark the end of a subscription, which are not directly related to a payment.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying this is perfectly normal. I guess this also means I should be testing to see which event it is and then decide my actions based on that.