# PayPal IPN notification receiving multiple notification for the same payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal-ipn

I would like to know why I'm receiving multiple IPN notification for one payment, and how I can stop this. I would like keep only one notification.

```
// STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

//$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    // my stuff goes here

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
```

Comment: how do you make this call? directly from this script or do you call from another script?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter , this script is called in controller

Comment: this is very strange, it always return one response each call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two posibilities came to my mind:

1. PayPal retries notification, if your handling script returns HTTP error.
2. For certain transations PayPal sends multiple notifications. Like for cheques. Or when transaction is later cancelled/refunded/reversed. You need to check payment status field for that.

Comment: thank you @martin-prikrly this what I get "status":"COMPLETED",

Comment: And did you check that your script return HTTP 200? E.g. check the your webserver log for the code returned. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758521/paypal-ipn-notification-twice

Comment: I found a dumb solution , 
the problem with IPN notification is that create multiple record on DB for one transaction , 
I modified the item id and customer id into unique , thx for all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very old post but i find this same issue on 2019
and you can simply fix this by adding

```
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

adding http header 200 ok in first line of your code.