# Paypal sending multiple IPN's

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using the paypal IPN to process payment from a website, it is all working fine and I am receiving a verified response and updating my orders in the Database accordingly. The issue I am having is that it is sending multiple IPN responses.

I understand that this could be because paypal is not receiving a 200 response when it hits my callback.

Everything is fine from what I can see. Is there anyway to "spoof" a 200 response or can anyone make out why a 200 response is not being sent from my callback?

Here is my callback:

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        //FH capture the callback in the callback table
        $callback = "";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
        {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
            $callback .= $key."=".$value."&";
        }

        Payment::insert_callback($callback);

        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";

        // $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";       
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

        // $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        $item_name = (isset($_POST['item_name']))? $_POST['item_name'] : $_POST['item_name1'];
        $item_number = (isset($_POST['item_number']))? $_POST['item_number'] : $_POST['item_number1'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];       
        if (!$fp) 
        {

        } 
        else 
        {
            fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
            while (!feof($fp)) 
            {
                $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
                $res = trim(str_replace('\n', '', $res));
                if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
                {
                        Payment::insert_callback('VERIFIED');
                        Payment::update_listing_history($item_number, 1, $callback);
                }
                else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
                {
                    Payment::insert_callback('INVALID');
                }
            }
            fclose ($fp);
        }
```

Comment: why would your script not be sending a 200 response?

Comment: I don't know. That is partly what I am asking "..can anyone make out why a 200 response is not being sent from my callback?"

Comment: There's an answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16015175/1352271 , although I'd like to ask if your checking against the database to see if the payments already been updated in the database before doing anything if it's an issue at all?